# Mule throwing exception for global functions using Groovy

Tags: groovy, mule

I am trying to define global functions in Mule. I have a file with multiple functions.  However, Mule is throwing an exception. My global function definition is as follows:

```
 <configuration doc:name="Configuration">
      <expression-language>
         <global-functions file="myscripts.groovy">
        </global-functions>
      </expression-language>
  </configuration>
```

The function definition that is causing the error is a legitimate groovy function as follows:

```
              def  convert(names,lookup){            
                    totals=[]
                    names.each{
                        name->
                        result=[:]
                        result['id']=1
                        result['value1']=lookup['code1']
                        result['value2']=lookup['code2']
                        result['value3']=lookup['code3']
                        totals.push(result)
                    }
                    totals
                }
```

The error that Mule is throwing is 
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
org.mule.module.launcher.DeploymentInitException: CompileException: [Error: unknown class or illegal statement: org.mule.mvel2.ParserContext@47b11ec7]
[Near : {... totals ....}]
                  ^
[Line: 12, Column: 31]
    at org.mule.module.launcher.application.DefaultMuleApplication.init(DefaultMuleApplication.java:212) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.8.3.jar:3.8.3]

What is the wrong with the definition that causing Mule to throw the error"

Please help!

Comment: When I added a return statement like, return totals; that error went away, but the next method which had a return statement starting failing.

Comment: No, worries I solved the problems